# Overloading Method with user input

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am new to java and I have an assignment to write a circle calculator program that computes the area, circumference and diameter of a circle. The program will accept input number (radius) and that number will be used to get the area, circumference and diameter of a circle. This time you are going to use separate methods for each computation. For example, to get the value of area you need to write method area that has radius parameter and returns double value.

I'm not sure if my code is right, I am getting zero values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Circle {
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private double radius;

public double getRadius() {
    System.out.print("Enter the radius: ");
    int radius = sc.nextInt();
    return radius;
}

public void setRadius(double radius) {
}

public double diameter() {
    double diameter = 2 * radius;
    return diameter;
}

public double area() {
    double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    return area;
}

public double circumference() {
    double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    return circumference;
}
}

public class Methods {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle circleTest = new Circle();

    System.out.printf("Radius: %.1f %n", circleTest.getRadius());
    System.out.printf("Diameter: %.1f %n", circleTest.diameter());
    System.out.printf("Area: %.1f %n", circleTest.area());
    System.out.printf("Circumference: %.1f %n", circleTest.circumference());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `getRadius` method you are setting a [local variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) to the value entered by the user:

`int radius = sc.nextInt();`

When you calculate the diameter, area, circumference you're using an [instance variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) - for example:

`double diameter = 2 * radius;`

Since you never set the instance variable its value [by default is 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: How can I set the instance variable to read the radius that was inputted by the user?

Comment: remove the `int` so that you're not declaring a new variable.